# How to clear data grid view after each selection of comboBox to retrive new data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

In my **View Items Form** I have comboBox that have two items "Packet and Piece" when I select index 0 it should retrive Packet data or select index 1 to retrive Piece data .. what should happen every time of different selection is the clear of data grid view **Rows and Columns** but it put the columns of previous selection on the new one .. where is the problem in my code? .. regards

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex==0)
            {
                viewItemsdgv.DataSource = null;
                viewItemsdgv.Rows.Clear();
                viewItemsdgv.Columns.Clear();
                dt.Clear();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("select itmBar as Barcode,itmTrdName as 'Trading name' ,itmScName as 'Scintfic name',pack as 'Pills in packet',tab as 'Pills in table',exdate as 'Expire date',packQuant as 'Packet quantity',tabQuant as 'Table quantity' from item where buyDflt !='buyDfltPiecerdb'", cn);
                da.Fill(dt);
                viewItemsdgv.DataSource = dt;
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                viewItemsdgv.DataSource = null;
                viewItemsdgv.Rows.Clear();
                viewItemsdgv.Columns.Clear();
                dt.Clear();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter("select itmBar as Barcode,itmTrdName as 'Trading name' ,pieceQuant as 'Pieces quantity',exdate as 'Expire date' from item where buyDflt='buyDfltPiecerdb'", cn);
                da.Fill(dt);
                viewItemsdgv.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @stuartd `DataBind()` is not available with Winform's `DataGridView`. It is for ASP.NET's `GridView`.

Comment: your code is redundant but it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing Columns of DataGridView, you need to remove columns of datatable (dt) as well.

Add

> dt.Columns.Clear();

Before

> dt.Clear();

Comment: sir thank you for your answer you solved my problem, I am still learning and your advice means a lot for me .. regards

Comment: Thank you. It was first time ever I contributed to Stack Overflow and I am glad that I was helpful to somebody.